# Why is the information from my foreign key not being updated?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table that lists a students information.

In the table only the student's name is local, the rest of the columns refer to foreign keys from other tables that have information regarding addresses and legal guardians.

The problem I have is when updating information in the address and guardian table the foreign key does not update in the student table.

Why is this?

This is how the table should update:

[image: This is how the table should update]

This is how the table updates when entering new data into each table:

[image: This is how the table updates when entering new data into each table]

Answer (score 0):

The foreign keys in your `students` table are used to uniquely identify a record using the primary keys in your `address` & `guardian` tables respectively.

Therefore, modifying the content of such records in your `address` & `guardian` tables will not change the value of the foreign key in the `students` table, as the same record is being identified.

Furthermore, adding new records to the `address` & `guardian` child tables will not automatically populate the foreign key of the `students` parent table, as there is no way to determine which record from the child tables should be selected.

To populate such fields, you should create a form whose record source is set to your `students` table, with appropriate subforms whose record sources point to each of the `address` & `guardian` child tables, and which are linked to the main form by the foreign keys in the parent table and primary keys in the child tables.

Then, when you create a new record through the subform, you can associate it with the active record displayed by the main form and the foreign key should be automatically populated by virtue of the fact that it is linked to the subform (providing you have referential integrity enabled).

Comment: What would recommend I do to have the foreign keys populate in the parent table when new data is added to the child tables?

Comment: I see, Is there any way to do this without using subforms? Perhaps queries?

Comment: @JordanBelson How would the query determine which child record should be assigned to the parent record?

Comment: They cannot. All of the information entered in the main form is entered and submitted as one. Can we use VBA code to have all of them associate with one another?

Comment: Because all of the new information is submitted as one unit, is there a way to let access know it is all related to one another?